# What would be the Recurrence Relation for the function and hence its time Complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

I can write a recurrence relation when the constant 'a' is not there but I am having a bit of confusion as 'a' and 'n' can have any values and hence both should be present in the Recurrence Relation.

```
void fun(int n)
{
     if(n<a)
     {
          printf("%d ",n);
          fun(n*2);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

provided that **a** is a constant, we can assume **c** to be another constant:

- T(n) = T(n*2) = T(n*4) = ... T(n*(2^i))
- n*(2^i) < a => 2^i < a/n => i < log(a) - log(n) => i < c

so

T(n) = T(n * c)

Therefore, the running time of **fun** is constant, no matter how big **a** is.

Comment: Shouldn't the running time be O(log(a) - log(n)) ?

Comment: Yes you can say that. But `log(a)` is a constant which is also reduced by `log(n)`, which makes the total running time to be dependent on **a** (upper-bounded by **log(a)**). Growth in the size of input doesn't affect the running time and therefore, the running time is constant.

Answer (score 0):

For all n > a, T(n) = c for some constant c (since no recursive calls are made in this case), so T(n) = O(1).